# Failed to execute goal com.mulesoft.munit.tools:munit-maven-plugin:1.3.2:test

Tags: mule, mule-component, anypoint-studio, munit, apikit

Hello Team, Created munit from APIkit router ,while running a mule maven project along with munit, I am facing Failed to execute goal com.mulesoft.munit.tools:munit-maven-plugin:1.3.2:test (test) error ,without munit I can able to run the project successfully. My Studio version : 6.2.5 Mule runtime : 3.8.4 ,

Munit POM config

```
<mule.version>3.8.4</mule.version>
        <mule.tools.version>1.2</mule.tools.version>
    <munit.version>1.3.2</munit.version>
    <mule.munit.support.version>3.8.3</mule.munit.support.version>
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow, please take a time to go through the [welcome tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to know your way around here (and also to earn your first badge), read how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also check [How to Ask Good Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so you increase your chances to get feedback and useful answers.

Answer (score 0):

There could be a few things wrong with your set up:

### Point to the correct `settings.xml` file

You will have a default `settings.xml` file in your project that you have to reference. Go to

**Window** > **Preferences** > **Maven** > *User Settings*

and point to your correct `settings.xml` file:

[image]

While you're there, make sure you have the correct 'm2-repository' configured as well (pictured above).

### Point to the correct installation of Maven

Ensure that you are referencing the correct installation of Maven. Go to

**Window** > **Preferences** > **Anypoint Studio** > *Maven*

and choose the correct path to your Maven installation:

[image]

### Make sure your build path is correct

Double-check your build path and make sure that it's correct.